# Where can I get a visa for Germany?

Tags: visas, germany, study

So I'm going to Germany in April for my master degree program and I have no idea where one gets a visa. Do you have to go to a consulate, or a courthouse like where you get a passport? I'm in Dubai.

Answer (score 5):

You need to go to the German consulate in Dubai. Checkout out this [link](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uae/dubai/how_to_apply.html) here. I presume you would be requiring a type D visa.

> The German Consulate in Dubai facilitates visa application process for
>   applicants residing in Dubai, Sharjah, Ras-Al-Khaimah, Fujairah, Ajman
>   or Umm-Al-Quwain.

The above link outlines some pointers which would be useful for your visa application. For more details also visit this [website](http://www.uae.diplo.de/Vertretung/uae/en/022-GKDubai/GK-Dubai-Hauptbereichsseite.html).

Comment: Does it make more sense to refer the visa applicant to the web site instead of the physical consulate? Some countries require an online application, and even for those who don't, the web site often offers an application form that can be downloaded and printed, which could save time and aggravation. Alternatively, if the form must be submitted in person, a visit to the web site beforehand would save a trip by allowing the applicant to bring the correct supporting documents.

Comment: Yeah I agree with your comment. Added a bit more information. However, it looks like even the official website directs to the link which I pointed out earlier in the answer.

Comment: Also contact the German university where you will do your Master, they might (surely?) have someone there to help you prepare all the needed paper work.